# What is the quadratic variation of compensated poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation

I want to know what is the quadratic variation of a compensated poisson process.

$$[N-\lambda t, N - \lambda t]_t = \sum_{0 \leq s \leq t} (\Delta (N_s - \lambda s))^2  = ? $$

This is as far as I can go. I am not sure how to proceed further.

I am more interested in the **steps** to derive the answer rather than the answer itself.

Comment: ... and we are more interested in your attempts to solve this question rather than the answer itself.

Comment: @saz please see update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Recall: $\Delta(f(s)-g(s)) = \Delta(f(s))-\Delta(g(s))$ for any two (deterministic) functions $f,g$.
2. Recall: $\Delta(f(s))=0$ if $f$ is continuous at $s$.
3. Using step 1,2 show that $$(\Delta (N_s-\lambda s))^2 = (\Delta N_s)^2.$$
4. Deduce from the fact that $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Poisson process that $$(\Delta N_s)^2 = \Delta N_s.$$
5. Conclude.

> **Solution:** $$[N_t-\lambda_t] = N_t.$$

Comment: Why is there a nested function f in step 2? And step 2 is suppose to illustrate the fact that $\Delta \lambda s =0$, right ? One more thing: how is step 4 derived mathematically? This is the part that I do not understand . Thanks

Comment: @mynameisJEFF Step 2: Sorry, was a typo. Step 4: A Poisson process has only jumps of height $1$, i.e. $\Delta N_s \in \{0,1\}$ for all $s \geq 0$. Hence, $$(\Delta N_s)^2 = \Delta N_s.$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? thanks...

Comment: We can write the quadratic covariation of a process $X$ as $[X, X]_{t} = [X, X]_{t}^{c} + X_{0}^{2} + \sum_{0 < s \leq t} (\Delta X_{s} ) ^{2}$, then the answer to this question follows almost immediately if we use the alternative expression of how to write $N_{t}$. The answer is $[N, N]_{t} = N_{t}$